# Creating a method with a parameter and when called can accept a parameter or not accept

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the method below in a react application. This method accepts a parameter.

```
    const displayModal = (p:Result) => {
        setConfirm(true);
        if(p) { //check variable for truthy
          setSelectedRow(p); 
        }    
      }
```

I want to be able to call this method with or without a parameter.
If I call the method without passing a parameter my code does not compile

```
    displayModal()
```

How can I write this such that I will be able to use the method
without passing a parameter as well.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? If so, you should add that as a tag. JS "compiling" would generally refer to using Babel to transpile, but your syntax would be invalid for that.

Comment: Yes I am using typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using TypeScript, you can simply specify an [optional or default parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters).

Either:

```
// optional
const displayModal = (p?:Result) => {}
```

or:

```
// default
const displayModal = (p:Result = new Result()) => {}
// new Result() can be anything that makes sense
```

They both let you call the method without providing a parameter.

The only real difference between the two is for optional, and the value would be `undefined` in the method. For default, the value would be your default value.